# How many set of integers $a,b,c,d$ are possible such that the polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ equals $1$ at, $x=19$ and $2$ at $x=62$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

My approach was to write $f(19) , f(62)$ in the format  where $f(x)= ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, then I tried to make some pattern by $f(-1)$ and $f(+1)$, please guide after this

Comment: Note that $f(19) \boldsymbol{\ne} f(62)$!! You even say it in your title! $f(19)=1$ and $f(62)=2$

Answer (score 4):

If $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients, then we have $f(x+m)\equiv f(x)\pmod m$ for all integers $x,m$. In particular, $$ f(62)\equiv f(19)\pmod{43}.$$